# How can I reference an inner object defined in another schema without explicitly specifying the whole path

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following files:

A.json

```
{
  "B": {
    "level1": {
      "abc": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

ASchema.json

```
{
  "$id": "ASchema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "B": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "BSchema.json#/definitions/B"
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "level1": {
              "properties": {
                "abc": {
                  "enum": [
                    "123"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

BSchema.json

```
{
  "$id": "BSchema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "B": {
      "$id": "#/definitions/B",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "level1"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "level1": {
          "$id": "#/definitions/B/properties/level1",
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "abc"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "abc": {
              "$id": "#/definitions/B/properties/level1/properties/abc",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to add a constraint for the inner object (B.level1.abc in BSchema.json) in ASchema.json without explicitly typing out the full path as I have done in the example above:

```
"properties": {
  "level1": {
    "properties": {
      "abc": {
        "enum": [
          "123"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to reference the inner object via its id? Something similar to:

```
{
  "$ref": {
    "BSchema.json#/definitions/B/properties/level1/properties/abc",
    "enum": [ "123" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer and then realise I missread your question. You CAN, but you SHOULDN'T, because the behaviour is inconsistent across implementations in some situations. We created a new keyword ($anchor) in draft 2019-09 to do specifically this, while specifying that the behaviour to do so with `$id` is not reliable or always supported. It's a confusing and tricky topic... more so than I can convey in this comment.

Comment: Feel free to join our (JSON Schema) community slack if you'd like to learn more on this.

Comment: There's no shorthand. JSON Schema is great, but it can be verbose sometimes. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion on slack, I understand your question a lot clearer.
You want to be able to reference a part of another schema directly without needing the full path.

To do that using JSON Schema draft-7, you must use a named $id. Here's a simplified example and [live demo](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASAlgE1ZFIALAFyIAdIB6CgUwA8BDAW1IBtqA6AYwHtGKBBAMqcC1RvXYArMN3ioANAmSo0YEWPq58xMpQrTZAWjWjx7bgCcA5hSwX6AMyKGADAHYKJjQGIFS-FjUDhjwGEQYsmBacEjI+ABC0f5x+Jg4UNok5FR0TKwcPHzxwqYSBnIgirEpqEQAnqTUWqjcAEaS1JxEftVxqBbUAI4ArhgD6XgA2skp+GwAbtQsAIyoM8gAulWz+KQW3I0W4dRRGTE7yiALS6tn67Mq2M0g3tcsPRd9IPQsLADyDi0kwcPzA1A292QAF97jDenDodt8D9-oCMtNeucHugBmi8KhiuozOVXtRFu8QDMEYgIfAoZUQBgoDB6VCgA).

```
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/ASchema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "B": {
      "$id": "http://example.com/BSchema.json",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "level1"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "level1": {
          "$id": "#level",
          "allOf": [false]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "BSchema.json#level"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me explain what's happening in this schema.

I have simplified your example by in-lining (or transcluding) BSchema into a definition. It doesn't matter what that definition is keyed by for this example, just that it's in a valid subschema location.

The subschema has a FULL URI `$id` of `http://example.com/BSchema.json`. This resets the base URI when evaluating an subschemas in that tree.

In BSchema properties, we define `level1` as having an $id of `#level'. This is like the id attribute in an HTML element.

To simplify the example, level1 is simply set to `false` to make the schema fail validation for the demo.

After the `definitions`, we reference `BSchema.json#level`. Note not "level1", so that property name can change.

Resolution happens by, looking at the base URI for the schema, which in this case is the root schema, and using URI resolution rules to determine the correct URI `http://example.com/BSchema.json`. Next the fragment of the URI is the target, and is found in the BSchema schema.